# Angular 2 recursive http.gets of unknown depth

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I've been using a pattern like the below to chain together http.gets in Angular2 to retrieve information from a hierarchical structure, two layers deep, of folders (all pseudotypescript):

```
myObservable = this.myService.getSubFolders(topFolderUrl)
    .switchMap(subFolders=> this.myService.getInfoFromSubFolders(subFolders))
    .map(subFolders=> => {
        ...do stuff with subFolders...
        return subFolders;
        }
    );
```

Where myService looks something like this:

```
getSubFolders(topFolderUrl): Observable<Folder[]> {
    return this.http.get(topFolderUrl)
        .map(res => {
            let body = res.json();
            let foldersToReturn: Folder[] = [];
            for (let subfolder of body.subFolders) {
                let tempFolder = new Folder;
                tempFolder.url = subfolder.url;
                tempFolder.otherProps = subfolder.otherPropValue;
            }
        return foldersToReturn;
        }
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

getInfoFromSubFolders(subFolders:Folder[]): Observable<Folder[]> {
    let calls: any[]  = [];

    for (let folder of subFolders:Folder){
        calls.push(
            this.http.get(folder.url)
            );

    var subject = new Subject<Folder[]>();       //see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38668416/2235210 for why Subject

    Observable.forkJoin(calls).subscribe((res: any) => {
        let foundFolder = subFolders.find(folder=> {
                return response.url.indexOf(folder.url)!==-1;
            });
        for (let response of res){
            let bodyAsJson = JSON.parse(response._body);
            foundFolder.otherProps = bodyAsJson.otherPropValue; 
        }
    subject.next(subFolders);
    });
return subject;
}
```

I then subscribe to myObservable using an | async pipe in my template. Object in myObservable ends up something like:

```
{
  "url": "topFolderUrl", 
  "otherProps": "otherPropsValue", 
  "subFolders": [
    {
      "url": "subFolder1Url",
      "otherProps": "otherPropsValue"
    },
    {
      "url": "subFolder2Url",
      "otherProps": "otherPropsValue",
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this relies on this structure of folders being exactly two layers deep - no more, no less I have two related questions:

1. How would I refactor this to allow me to recursively work my way down a series of folder *n* layers deep - I can only request one layer at a time - i.e each subFolder has "subFolders": [] and so on.
2. How would I allow the system to cope if there were no subFolders? ie not call getInfoFromSubFolders in the .switchMap

I have a feeling this this is a very common scenario so it is likely to be useful to many people.

Any pointers gratefully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the `expand` operator could help you here since it tackles recursion in such use cases.

See this question for more details:

- [Make a second http call and use the result in same Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308866/make-a-second-http-call-and-use-the-result-in-same-observable/38308968?noredirect=1)

Comment: Thanks @Thierry Templier looks as if that will do exactly what I need...and cope with giving back an empty observable! I'll give it a try later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post when breaking my head to implement
[an other problem to do with recursivity and Observables](https://cocoboulot.blogspot.co.uk/2017/12/recursivity-and-observables-yes-it-is.html). Fortunately, I am able now to answer your question.

*The problem to resolve*
Starting from a folder provided as an argument, you would like to visit all sub-folders. For every sub-folder, visit all sub-folders and repeat this process without a limit in depth.

To answer your question about refactoring and model, this problem is a typical [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for which options are available for data structures.

You did not provide much detail about your Folder but let’s make some assumptions. Your class has the following properties:

- parent: Folder
- children: Folder[]

You currently have a service that returns children for a given folder. Let’s assume the method signature is:

```
myObservable: Observable<Folder[]> = this.myService.getSubFolders(aFolder);
```

**An approach using recursivity**

For implementing a recursive approach it helps to create a context that will contain the (under construction) result and any other properties needed for the state of the recursion: FolderTraversalContext .

```
processSubFolders(ctx: FolderTraversalContext): Observable<FolderTraversalContext> {
  return this.getSubFolders(ctx.folder)
    .map( folders: Folder[] => {
      folders.forEach( f => {
        f.parent = folder;
        ctx.toVisit.push(f);
      });
      folder.children = folders; 

      //Prepare for next cycle
      ctx.complete = ctx.toVisit.length() === 0;
      if (! ctx.complete) {
        ctx.folder = ctx.toVisit[0];
        ctx.toVisit.splice(0,1);
      }
      return ctx;
    }
}
```

**Use of expand operator**

The method that implements the recursion in a reactive way looks like this then:

```
readAllSubfolders(topFolder: Folder): Observable<Folder> {
  const ctx = new FolderTraversalContext();
  ctx.topFolder = topFolder;
  ctx.complete = false;
  ctx.toVisit = [];
  ctx.folder = topFolder;

  return Observable.of(ctx)
    .expand( ctx => {
      return (ctx.completed) ? Observable.empty() : this.processSubFolders(ctx);
    })
    .map(ctx => ctx.topFolder);
}
```

Allez!