# How to load multiple rest requests

Tags: angular

I have to do multiple GET Requests to load data from an external page.

The response of the a request might return a flag that indicates that there is more data to load:
  "nextPage" : "/v1/catalog/products?page=2&pageSize=10",

Below is the code of my function.

I tried to implement a do while loop but I couldn't make it work. I guess there is also a smarter way to do this - maybe Switchmap?

**Old Version**

```js
  loadCatalog() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<Catalog[]>(ZUORA_URL + '/v1/catalog/products?page=1&pageSize=10', { headers })
              .pipe(map(data => data))
              .subscribe(data => {
                this.catalog = data;
                resolve(true);
            });
    });
}
```

I want to load the complete data and store it in one place. How can I loop until there is no additional nextpage? - loading one page after another is now working but I'm still struggeling to store the responses...

**Updated Version**

```js
  getProducts(url, dataSoFar = []): Observable<any[]> {
    if (!url) {
      return of (dataSoFar);
    } else {
      url = ZUORA_URL + url;
    }
    return this.http.get<any>(url, { headers }).pipe(
      switchMap(p => this.getProducts( p.nextPage, [...dataSoFar, ...p.data]))
    );
  }

  getData() {
    return this.getProducts('/v1/catalog/products');
  }
```

Comment: Off-topic, but I am really not sure it is recommended to wrap the observable with a Promise and update data as a side-effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308866/make-a-second-http-call-and-use-the-result-in-same-observable/38308968?noredirect=1 

Look at this. It might solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`expand`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand) to call your api recursively and [`reduce`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce) to reduce all the responses to a single array.

In your `Service` (MyService):

```ts
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { expand, reduce, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

baseUrl = ZUORA_URL;

// Let's say you get an object like this from your API
interface ApiResponse {
  nextPage: string,
  data: any[]
}

public fetchData(apiEndpoint: string): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(baseUrl + apiEndpoint, { headers })
    .pipe(
      // recursively call the GET requests until there is no further 'nextPage' url
      expand(apiResponse => {
        if (!apiResponse.nextPage) {
          return EMPTY;
        }
        return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(apiResponse.nextPage, { headers });
      }),
      // map the api response to the data we actually want to return
      map(apiResponse => apiResponse.data),
      // reduce the data of all GET requests to a single array
      reduce((accData, data) => accData.concat(data))
    )
}
```

In your Component:

```ts
private products: Product[];

loadProducts() {
  this.myService.fetchData('/v1/catalog/products').subscribe(products => 
    this.products = products as Product[]
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi Fridoo,

the application shows an error after the third request:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

do you have an idea what is causing the issue?

Comment: @Malte try to specify an empty array as the seed in the `reduce` function: `reduce((accData, data) => accData.concat(data), [])`

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure if it is recommended to wrap the observable with a Promise and update data as a side-effect.

```
loadCatalog(URL) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<Catalog[]>(ZUORA_URL + URL , { headers })
          .pipe(map(data => data))
          .subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can chain the requests to get back the data as below

```
async loadAllCatalogs(URL) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try { 
    let catalogs = [];
    let data = await this.loadCatalog('/v1/catalog/products?page=1&pageSize=10');
    catalogs.push(data); // store catalog as an array since there may be more results based on nextPage key
    while(data.nextPage) {
       data = await this.loadCatalog(data.nextPage);
       catalogs.push(data);
    }
    resolve(catalogs);
    }
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are wrapping an observable with a promise instead of using `flatMap` or `toPromise`.  It makes no sense. Observables can receive multiple values. Promises cannot. Why even use the observable at all if you are going to break it?

Comment: I had already added a comment below the original question before attempting to answer and also titled my answer with the same. But then again, HTTP GET request DOES NOT return multiple values, so what is the point ? Also, Promises are easier to handle with async/await, observables cannot be, so there is another reason for the same :)

Comment: And even though it 'breaks' convention, it is still working code that solves a pain the author had. It sucks when people can't realise that :D

Answer (score 0):

Usually when things are paged, you want to only fetch things when a user actively requests them. However, I'm going to just answer your question as it stands and leave the lecture out.

I'm not sure how you would have `nextPage` included when you're expecting an array as your top-level in the response, so I'm going to assume the response is actually of the form:

```js
interface CatalogResponse {
  nextPage: string | undefined;
  products: Catalog[];
}
```

In order to do this, you could use an `Observable`.

```js
public loadProducts(url: string): Observable<Catalog[]> {
  let nextPage: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  let products: Subject<Catalog[]> = new Subject<Catalog[]>();

  nextPage.subscribe((url: string) => {
    this.fetchProducts(url, products, nextPage);
  }).add(() => products.complete());

  return products;
}

private fetchProducts(url: string, products: Subject<Catalog[]>, nextPage: Subject<string>): void {
  this.http.get<CatalogResponse>(url, { headers })
          .subscribe(response => {
            products.next(response.products);
            if (response.nextPage) {
              nextPage.next(response.nextPage);
            } else {
              nextPage.complete();
            }
          });
}
```

You'll want to make sure you implement a "cancel" or "stop" operation in case this goes on indefinitely.