# RxJs/Angular loading from multiple HTTP requests and updating model from each request

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have been using Angular/RxJS for a few weeks and have various models that are built from multiple REST requests which I have thus far achieved using switchMap(). Here is a simple contrived example (stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o1djbb):

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Order {
  id: string;
  itemName: string;
  details?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  order: Order;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrderFromApi(123)
      .subscribe(item => this.order = item);
  }

  getOrderFromApi(id): Observable<Order>  {
    const item$ = this.getItemName(id);
    const fullItem$ = item$.pipe(
      switchMap(n => {
        console.log(`Got name: '${n}''`);
        return this.getDetails(n);
      },
        (nameReq, detailsReq) => ({ id: '123', itemName: nameReq, details: detailsReq })
      ));
    return fullItem$;
  }

  getItemName(id): Observable<string> {
    return this.fakeXhr('foo');
  }

  getDetails(itemName): Observable<string> {
    console.log(`Got details '${itemName}''`)
    return this.fakeXhr('Some details about foo');
  }

  fakeXhr(payload: any) {
    return of(payload)
      .pipe(delay(2000));
  }
}
```

And a simple template:

```
<p>
  item: {{order && order.itemName}}
</p>
<p>
  details: {{order && order.details}}
</p>
```

This works but the order info is not rendered until **both** requests complete. What I would like to happen is for the *itemName* to render as soon as it's available and then details to render when they become available. Hence taking advantage of the multiple values that Observables can emit. Eg:

```
// first value emitted:
{ itemName: 'foo', details: null }
// second value emitted:
{ itemName: 'foo', details: 'Some details about foo' }
```

I realise I could probably achieve this with a BehaviourSubject or using Redux (as I have in the past with React), but feel there is a simple solution I can't quite grasp due to the newness of all this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`expand`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand) to emit the data from the first request straight away and subsequently do the second request.

`expand` will call the inner request recursively, getting the `order` from the last request as input, so we only execute the second request when the `order` has no `details` and end the recursion otherwise with an `EMPTY` Observable.

```
import { Observable, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { map, expand } from 'rxjs/operators';

getOrderFromApi(id): Observable<Order> {
  return this.getItemName(id).pipe(
    map(itemName => ({ id, itemName, details: null } as Order)),
    expand(order => order.details
      ? EMPTY
      : this.getDetails(order.itemName).pipe(
        map(details => ({ id, itemName: order.itemName, details } as Order))
      )
    )
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umqyem

The returned Observable will emit:

1. `{ "id": 123, "itemName": "foo", "details": null }`
2. `{ "id": 123, "itemName": "foo", "details": "Some details about foo" }`

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as I think it's the most elegant solution (currently at least).

We could take this further and use the _index_ from expand something like so: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btso9u?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, `expand` is also well suited for executing an unknown amount of requests like when you're dealing with pagination. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54293624/9423231

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your best choice is to substitute `mergeMap()`  for `switchMap()`?

> https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/
>
> As we can see, the values of the merged source Observables show up
>   immediately in the output. The result Observable will not be completed
>   until all the merged Observables are completed.

I would definitely check out these articles:

- [Comprehensive Guide to Higher-Order RxJs Mapping Operators: switchMap, mergeMap, concatMap (and exhaustMap)](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) (cited above)
- [RxJS: When to Use switchMap](https://blog.angularindepth.com/when-to-use-switchmap-dfe84ac5a1ff)

Comment: A direct substitute won't certainly won't work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8canj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Fork that stackblitz and show us how!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of persisting your full item at the end of the observable stream (i.e. in your `.subscribe` block) you could store the received values within the respective parts of your code, namely after they are available:

```
 switchMap(n => {
        console.log(`Got name: '${n}''`);
        this.order.name = n;
        return this.getDetails(n);
      },
```

... and then in your sibscription block you would only have to store the advanced information:

```
this.getOrderFromApi(123)
      .subscribe(item => this.order.details = item.details);
```

Obviously, this requires you to initialize your ´order´ attribute accordingly, e.g. with `order: Order = {};` or `order: Order = new Order();`.

Basically, the idea is to restructure your code s.t. your observable stream emits partial values (your order's attributes) instead of a full-blown object.

Comment: This might work in this contrived example, but in reality the getOrderFromApi() would be in a service and then the only way to achieve the above would be to pass a reference to an object into it _getOrderFromApi(this.order)_ which is not really what I was after. I want multiple values emitted from the returned Observable.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I did come up with was to just create an Observable and call next(). I'd be interested to hear any opinion on this.

```
getOrder(id) {
    const ob$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
      const item$ = this.getItem(id)
        .pipe(
          tap(o => subscriber.next(({ id: id, itemName: o.itemName, details: null }))),
          switchMap(o => this.getDetails(o.itemName),
            (o, d) => ({ id: id, itemName: o.itemName, details: d.details })
          ),
          tap(a => subscriber.next(a))
        );
      item$.subscribe(a => {
        subscriber.complete();
      });
    });

    return ob$;
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mybvli